# The constructor EventUpdater(EventDetails, Event) is undefined

Tags: android

I am getting a following compile time errors.Below I am pointed out the error line.

> The constructor EventUpdater(EventDetails, Event) is undefined

**EventDetails.java:**

```
package com.steph.event;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class EventDetails extends Fragment {
    private Event eve;
    private Users usr;

@Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_details, container, false);
     return v;
    }

private void saveEventDetails() {

String strAuthenticator = "email=" + usr.getEmail() + "&sig="
                + usr.getPassword();
        if (isNew) // call the POST method to create new event
            (new EventUpdater(this, eve)).execute("?" + strAuthenticator,  ----> Compile Error
                    "POST");
        else
            // call the PUT method to update the current event
            (new EventUpdater(this, eve))                  ----->Compile Error
                    .execute("?" + strAuthenticator, "PUT");

    }

}
```

**EventUpdater.java:**

```
package com.steph.event;

public class EventUpdater extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private final ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Activity mContext;
    JSONObject oJSONObject = new JSONObject();
    Event oEvent = new Event();

    /*
     * Default constructor to set the current activity and event object as a
     * reference
     */
    public EventUpdater(Activity ct, Event pry) {
        this.mContext = ct;
        this.oEvent = pry;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    }
  }
```

I didn't know how to solve this compile error.Anybody can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing "this" which refer to fragment not activity So Pass Activity context on constructor parameter.

```
EventUpdater(this, eve))
```

solved as

```
EventUpdater(getActivity(), eve))
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thank you works fine will accept your answer after few minutes.Now it shows some error.

Answer (score 1):

try this way in `Fragment`

```
  new EventUpdater(getActivity(), eve).execute("?" + strAuthenticator,"POST");
```